# Checkbox values not saved in repeating rows

Tags: javascript, checkbox, xhtml, repeat

I have a table that allows users to add additional rows as needed. I am trying to add checkboxes as one of the input methods in the table, which partially works. If there is only one row on the table, the values are saved, however if additional rows are added, the checkbox values are only saved on one row (the last one). Can anyone tell me if there is a way to make these values unique so each one is saved?

Example code:

```
<table>
  <xsl:for-each select="departments/department"> //repeating section as defined on xml
   <tr repeat="row1" delete="row1">
    <td class="propertycontent">
     <input type="checkbox" id="[xml ID] name="[xml ID]"
     onclick="saveCheckbox(this, '[checkboxname]');">
     <xsl:if test="[xml ID] = '1'">
      <xsl:attribute name="checked">true</xsl:attribute>
     </xsl:if>
     <input type="hidden" name"[checkboxname]" id="[checkboxname]">
      <xsl:attribute name="value"><xsl:value-of select="[xml ID]"></xsl:attribute>
     </input>
     </label for="[checkboxname]">Checkbox 1</label>
    </td>
   </tr>
  </xsl:for-each>
 </table>
```

Is there something else I need to add to my table code to save all values or does this need to be done with javascript?

Comment: I assume `[xml ID]` is unique for every row, correct?

Comment: No and this is where my problem is. I want the user to be able to add as many rows as they need, without me having to create a unique xml ID for each row they could possibly add.

Comment: In order for the value of each input to be sent to the server, it *must* have a unique name. This is defined in the [HTML specification](http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/interact/forms.html#successful-controls). The problem is you are not giving each input a unique name. Instead you are doing `name="[xml ID]"` where `[xml ID]` does not change. The form is incapable of distinguishing between multiple inputs with the same name; therefore it sends the value of the last input. Without further information on what `saveCheckBox()` does, that's all the help I can provide.